# Generating row no from sorted by date table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to sort table by logintime (desc) and generate the row numbers. My MySQL query shows different results on my localhost (which I want) and hosting (not properly sorted):

```
SELECT
    @curRow := @curRow + 1 as 'rowno', sortedtable.*
FROM
    (SELECT @curRow := 0) indextable
JOIN
    (SELECT logins.logintime
        FROM logins ORDER BY logins.logintime DESC
    ) sortedtable
```

Result from localhost:

[image: Result from localhost]

Result from hosting:

[image]

Both logintime columns already have the same column type, 'datetime'. Why on hosting not properly sorted by logintime (desc)?

**Edit: Turned out that MySQL version is 5.5**

Since 5.7 it ignores ORDER BY in derived tables.

> ORDER BY in derived table or view
>
> ORDER BY in the subquery/view is handled differently in 5.7 compared
>   to 5.6: It is ignored unless the outer query is non-aggregated and
>   contains only one table reference (i.e the reference to this derived
>   table or view). It is also ignored if the outer query itself contains
>   an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Does it work if `ORDER BY logins.logintime DESC` is moved outside the `JOIN`?

Comment: @DhruvSaxena Yes it works if moved outside the Join.